# Sentry doesn't show code in stack trace for react native application

Tags: react-native, sentry

- React Native version: 0.65.3
- Sentry CLI version: 1.74.4

I uploaded the source map and bundle for my react native application to sentry and logged some errors. The source map and bundle are working fine. The line numbers in the stack trace from the bundle perfectly map to line numbers on source map. (https://reactnative-archive-august-2023.netlify.app/docs/0.65/symbolication)

But, sentry output looks like this. It doesn't show the code. Also, the stack frames don't expand when clicked. I tried the `minified` version of the stack trace but still no luck.

[image]

I ran `sentry-cli sourcemaps explain` command for an issue and gave me this output.

```
✔ Fetched data for event: <event-id>
✔ Event has release name: <release-name>
✔ Event has a valid exception present
✔ Event has a valid stacktrace present
⚠ Exception is already source mapped and first resolved frame points to:

> [missing context line]
```

I think the issue is with `[missing context line]`. So, my question is how should I debug this and show code blocks in the sentry error stack trace?